# Write pins with specific list of users with access (acl)

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, posit-connect

I would like to write pins to my Posit Connect board with acl, by that I mean a list of specific users that get access.

I need to do this via code instead of Posit Connect GUI because I have thousands of pins (that get updated regularly).

The following code uploads mtcars as a pin to my Posit Connect board with access_type "logged_in" ("All users - login required").

```
library(pins)
board <- board_connect(auth = "envvar")

mtcars %>% pins::pin_write(board = board, name = "my_mtcars_pin",
                               force_identical_write = T, access_type = "logged_in")
```

Other options are "all" and "acl". With "acl" I would have to supply a list of users or groups. I don't know how to to that, I can't find any documentation on this. Could someone please provide me with an example? Thank you very much!

I wonder if I could use connectapi::get_acl_user() or connectapi::get_acl() for my purposes but for that I would need the GUID for the content item to be retrieved. The GUID is not provided with functions from the pins library (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Not sure if this is the best way to do it - probably not - but it does work at least.

```
library(dplyr)
library(connectapi)

# connect object to Posit board
connect <- connectapi::connect(
  server = Sys.getenv("CONNECT_SERVER"),
  api_key = Sys.getenv("CONNECT_API_KEY"))

# get all content
myguids <- connectapi::get_content(connect, limit = Inf)
# filter for specific content by name
# (here: use an object that has the specific acl set that I'd like elsewhere)
# probably could also just search for user GUIDS via connectapi
content <- myguids %>% dplyr::filter(name == "report_a")
# create a R6 content object
content_r6 <- connectapi::content_item(
  connect = connect, guid = content$guid)

# get user permission
users_guid <- connectapi::get_content_permissions(
  content_r6, add_owner = FALSE) %>% dplyr::pull(principal_guid)

# get the content I want to update
content2 <- myguids %>% dplyr::filter(name == "my_mtcars_pin")
# create a R6 content object
content2_r6 <- connectapi::content_item(
  connect = connect, guid = content2$guid)

# update access_type to acl if not set like this anyway yet
connectapi::content_update_access_type(
  content = content2_r6, access_type = "acl")
# set new owners
connectapi::content_add_user(
  content = content2_r6, guid = users_guid, role = "owner")
```